# Retrieve one column with different values using foreign key

Tags: mysql

I wanted to select one column horizontally with different values using foreign key. This foreign key reference from another table name `gradingperiod_id`.

```
first | second
   80      81
```

grades:

```
grade_id | grade | gradingperiod_id 
  1          80         7001
  2          81         7002
```

gradeperiod_mt:

```
gradeperiod_id | period
     7001           1
     7002           2
```

student_grade:

```
student_grade_id | student_id | grade_id
        1            20140540      1
        2            20140540      2
```

I tried to query like this but these gives me multiple row vertically with same values.

```
first | second
  80      80
  81      81

SELECT 1st.grade AS first, 2nd.grade as second FROM student_grade sg
INNER JOIN grade 1st ON 1st.grade_id = sg.grade_id
INNER JOIN grade 2nd ON 2nd.grade_id = sg.grade_id

WHERE sg.student_id = 20140540

GROUP BY 1st.grade, 2nd.grade;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a *pivot*, see [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) for many solutions.

```
SELECT MAX(IF(g.grade_id = 1, g.grade, 0)) AS first,
       MAX(IF(g.grade_id = 2, g.grade, 0)) AS second
FROM grades AS g
JOIN student_grade as sg ON sg.grade_id = g.grade_id
WHERE sg.student_id = 20140540
```

There's no need for `ORDER BY` since this only returns 1 row.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbf533/2)

Comment: Lol. I forgot that I'm trying to create a pivot table.  `MAX` method did the  trick. :)